# Python 3.2.3 running error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I using this code to get the organization in ip address

```
import urllib 
import lxml.html as lh
req= urllib.Request("http://www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
html = urllib.urlopen(req).read()
doc = lh.fromstring(html)
print (''.join(doc.xpath('.//*[@class="odd"]')[-1].text_content().split()))
```

My python is 3.2.3, it shows

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext.py", line 3, in <module>
  req= urllib.Request("http:// www.ip-address.com/ip_tracer/157.123.22.11", headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Request'
```

how to solve it. Thanks,

Comment: BTW: Is the space between `http://` and `www.ip-address.com` useful in any way?

Comment: Please don't edit the question like this. Your original question has been answered. Accept an answer and open a new question for your new problem.

Comment: This question is tagged urllib3, any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use [`urllib.request.Request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request), import it like this:

```
import urllib.request

r = urllib.request.Request(...)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(r).read()
```

If you need nothing else from `urllib.request`, you can import only `Request`:

```
from urllib.request import Request

r = Request(...)
```